# A div between text element characters

Tags: javascript

I have a text element that is built when the user clicks a button. In the middle of that text, I want to add an input element but I could not find a way.
I actually made a lot of things but here are the important ones So, First I made an input element and a button when the user enter input and click the button what he wrote will be displayed in a h1 element with a random missing word I want to make an input element and I want it to be in the same place that the missing word should've been in.

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("inputed");
  x = x.substr(0, c) + x.substr(d, x.length);

  const z = x.length;

  //I want an input element to be between the charAt(c) and charAt(d)
  y.innerHTML = `${x.slice(
        0,
        c
    )}<input type="text" style="color: gray;border:2px solid;border-radius: 10px;outline: none;font-size: x-large;height:40px;width: 100px;" >${x.slice(
        d,
        z
    )} `;
  console.log(z);
}
```

The problem is when I enter this code it doesn't display all the text after the input element it misses about 7 characters
That is all!I will be extremly happy if someone helps me.

Comment: It looks like you shouldn't re-assign a substring to `x`, just keep its original value, and assing the substring to a new variable. If that doesn't fix the problem, please make a [mre].

Comment: Thanks!Well the problem was pretty simple.All what I had to do was delete x = x.substr(0, c) + x.substr(d, x.length);